# Ignore file in sub directory?

Tags: git

I've tried a lot of patterns, but non of them works, and the file still synced with the remote server (GitHub):
I have a text file inside the project folder:

```
ProjFolder
   secret.txt
.gitignore
```

I want to ignore the file secret.txt. 
I tried:

```
./secret.txt
/secret.txt
*/secret.txt
```

and a lot more that I can't remember.
Is it possible to ignore file that's not in the same .gitignore directory?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ignore it from now on, you should use

```
git rm --cached project/secret.txt
cat project/secret.txt >> .gitignore
git commit -a -m "Remove secret.txt"
```

Ignore rule will be effective only after you removed that file.

If you want to remove it from all history, you should search usage of `git filter-branch` and rewrite all history to remove this file.

Comment: `git rm project/secret.txt` is a rather harsh advice. :-(

Comment: @phd Sorry, I have add `--cached` to rm

Comment: @phd why please? I'd like to know

Comment: `git rm` removes the file from disk and I'm sure you want to keep it in the directory but not in the repository. `git rm --cached` removes the file from repository but not from disk.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify it's path in your `.gitignore` file:

```
ProjFolder/secret.txt
```

Comment: I tried this also, didn't work